# Intersection of Line and Axes not visible on Desmos for solved equation.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

This is a Desmos graph I made to visualise the F-Distribution.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x68zy3i9vj

In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvc3W.png), on the left B(a,b) is the Beta Function, B1(x,a,b) is the Incomplete Beta Function

and the I(x,a,b) is the Regularized Incomplete Beta Function. Don't worry about them.

The C(x) is the Cumulative Distribution Function. d1 and d2 are degrees of freedom

and are constants.

Here's what I want to do: I want to find the value of x for which C(x)=0.95.

I did [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWvRl.png) to solve this problem and got the purple vertical line.

The point of intersection of this vertical line and the x-axis would be the desired value.

However, Desmos isn't letting me click on the line and the point of intersection isn't visible.

How do I go about getting the point of intersection? Is there any other easy way to find this x-value on desmos?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).